# C# pass date between two forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
     SubMenu1 SubMenu = new SubMenu1();
     SubMenu.ShowDialog();
}
```

Hi,I have two forms (form 1 and form 2) in form1 there are 5 button,In form2 there is a text box,Now what i want to do when i click on the button in form 1,form2 load and display on the text box "1",each and every button have a number.How can i do this???help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass data via constructor. I.e. change constructor of SubMenu1 form to accept integer value and show it in textbox:

```
public SubMenu1(int value)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

Then pass value when creating instance of SubMenu1 form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
     SubMenu1 SubMenu = new SubMenu1(1);
     SubMenu.ShowDialog();
}
```

NOTE: You can use single even handler for all buttons (assume all buttons have names button1...buttonN):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
     Button button = (Button)sender;         
     int value = Int32.Parse(button.Name.Substring(6)); // or use button.Tag
     SubMenu1 SubMenu = new SubMenu1(value);
     SubMenu.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you are going to have to pass the value that needs to be displayed from `Form1` to `SubMenu1`.  The easiest way is to add a parameter to the constructor to carry the value.

```
SubMenu1 SubMenu = new SubMenu1("1");
SubMenu.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass values between forms, it is best practive to pass them in the constructor. That means that the class that is form 2 needs to have a constructor that takes an int (in your case because you want to pass a number) as an argument. Then you can use that variable inside your second form.

Remember that a form is just an object. I don't know how much you are into Object Oriented Programming, but you can have a constructor for the second form just as for any other object.

Answer (score 0):

how to pass values between forms, the basic is create constructor for the form2

```
public Form2(string s1) : this ()
{
  yourTextbox.Text = s1;
}
```

then in form 1 button click event

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(yourString);
frm.ShowDialog();
```